# com.coronalabs.template App Store Publishing error

Tags: ios, app-store, coronasdk

I am getting a number of errors after uploading our binary for publishing to the Apple app store. For details see http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/41367-comcoronalabstemplate-app-store-publishing-error/ . The original poster was able to solve the problem, but we have had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the "Certificates and KeyChain" in App ID's.
Here's what I did to fix it. 
Hopefully this will help anyone who's having this issue.

1. Backup all your current AppStore Certificates.
2. Remove all your current AppStore Certificates.
3. Copy your certificate and provisioning profiles to this path :

   > /Users/{YOUR-USERNAME}/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
4. Re-install your AppStore Distribution Certificate.
5. Re-submit through Application Loader.

Worked for me :)