# Why do I have this error uploading to the appstore with corona sdk?

Tags: ios, coronasdk, appstore-approval

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entlitements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle containts a key value is not allowed: '["BG2J43EA88.com.coronalabs.template"]' for the key 'keychain-access-groups' in 'MicroNight.app/MicroNight' at softwareAssets/SoftwareAsse.

My build.settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAHe1.jpg

Somebody know why?

Answer (score 0):

Had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889861/com-coronalabs-template-app-store-publishing-error), we use this hack to upload to the appstore. May or may not work for you.

- Delete everything from /Users/{YOUR-USERNAME}/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
- Delete anything apple related in your keychain(after backing them up)
- Download the distribution provisioning profile and certificate from your account
- Reinstall the certificate to keychain by double clicking it, and copy the certificate and distribution profile to /Users/{YOUR-USERNAME}/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
- Open corona simulator to app repo and build using iOS option
- Use application loader(opened seperatly from Corona) to deliver the zip file that is generated